# Restore purchases with RMStore

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, rmstore

I'm trying to get the RMStore library to work, but therefore I need to be able to restore the in app purchases the user could have possible made. I'm aware of the method: *restoreTransactionsOnSuccess:* but with this method I don't get to know **which** in app purchases are restored.

```
[[RMStore defaultStore] restoreTransactionsOnSuccess:^{



} failure:^(NSError *error) {



}];
```

The above code is what I used, and it's working because in the logging I see the bought in app purchases. Do I miss something?

Could somebody point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the part of library with notifications. Is's easyer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Merlea Dan mentioned, you can achieve this with notifications. The RMStore [documentation](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore#payment-transaction-notifications) states:

> Payment transaction notifications are sent after a payment has been
>   requested or for each restored transaction.

Simply register as an observer and implement:

```
- (void)storePaymentTransactionFinished:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    SKPaymentTransaction *transaction = notification.rm_transaction;
    if (transaction.state == SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored) 
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

It's worth mentioning that a few others have requested to have `restoreTransactionsOnSuccess` return the list of restored product ids in the success block. You might want to subscribe to this [issue](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore/issues/53) in case it gets added.

Comment: Thank you @hpique for your message. Unfortunately it isn't working. The notification's _transaction_ property is nil which doesn't help me to find out which products are restored. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If `notification.rm_transaction` in `storePaymentTransactionFinished:` is returning nil, then yes, it's a bug. Are you using the latest version, though? The property was renamed to `rm_transaction` a while back.

Comment: The property _rm_transaction_ does not exist in the release I have, _transaction_ does. My current version of RMStore is 0.5.2

Comment: Oops, you're right. I forgot to push the update. Can you post a bug report in the RMStore repo with as much relevant code as possible? It's odd. If this were a bug in `storePaymentTransactionFinished:` more people should be complaining.

Comment: I think there was a misunderstanding about the specific method we were discussing. I was talking about `- (void)storeRestoreTransactionsFinished:` that notification is actually a NSString. But I (finally) found out that when a product has been restored the `- (void)storePaymentTransactionFinished:` gets called, there I can retrieve the bundle identifier to take action in my app. My problem is solved, thank you very much!